# Returning a resultset from one page to another in PHP

Tags: php, resultset

I have 2 php pages: `query.php` and `result.php`.

In `query.php`, I am executing a query (select) statement. It's returning a resultset

```
$rs = mysql_query($query);
```

Now I want to return this resultset from `query.php` to another page `result.php` and work with it. Like this:

In `query.php`:

```
return $rs
```

and in `result.php`:

```
$result = executeQuery($query) // we get the resultset in this variable
while ($row == mysql_fetch_array($result){
//do something 
}
```

If the above is not recommended, please provide me with alternatives. But I want the query function and resultset in different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just include results.php in your query.php page if you're just looking to keep the code separate in the source files but aren't actually required to redirect from one page to another:

In query.php:

```
$rs = mysql_query($query);
include "results.php";
```

In results.php:

```
while ($row == mysql_fetch_array($rs){
  //do something 
}
```

As far as trying to "return $rs" from one page to another that's not how PHP works.  The return statement is only valid within a function.  If you want to actually pass data from one PHP page to another and will be redirecting to that other page then you'll need to use either a session, a cookie, pass it in the URL (i.e. use GET) or use curl and add it as a POST var.

Comment: but returning an array from page to page is possible isnt it? so if i can make an array in query.php page and return it to results.php page, i can use it. but stuck on how to do it? any help pls?

Comment: You can't "return" something from one page to another.  You return a result from a function to the location in code that called that function.  You can't just create an array in a page and "return it" to another page.  Perhaps if you gave more details of why you want to have two PHP files in the first place (edit your original post don't add the details in this comment thread) we could offer more help.

Comment: ok, now i understand.. i am trying to keep it seperate in 2 diff pages so i can re-use.

Comment: You can re-use it as an include file which is what a lot of people do.  See http://php.net/include and http://php.net/require for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really the way it must be, store the result set in a database somewhere or in a file and give each result a unique name. Then pass that name to the next page so it can be retrieved.

`query.php` will redirect to `result.php?result_set=ab24sdfsdfklls` for instance.

This has the added advantage that you can use the result_set as often as you want. Visitors can have multiple result sets during one visit. They can share the URL of the result set page with other people, etc.

Just be sure to eventually prune the data store as it will just keep on growing, but that's another matter entirely.

Comment: But how can i send the resultset in the URL? the resultset returns a resource id, isnt it.. if we send that in the URL, how can we retrieve the data from the resourceid in the URL? pls help